# Maven Error: Cannot find 'version' in class org.springframework.boot.maven.Exclude

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I encountered a problem with running my spring-boot application using the terminal. In IDE (IntelliJ) app starts perfectly, but when I try to run it by `mvn clean spring-boot:run` an error occurs.

```
shell
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.020 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-17T09:35:14+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:run (default-cli) on project tobebought: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:run for parameter version: Cannot find 'version' in class org.springframework.boot.maven.Exclude -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

I tried changing the version of spring-boot as well as adding the `<version\>` tag to the parent dependency. Also, I tried deleting the `.m2` folder and downloading all dependencies again.
Maven is up to date because I tried to reinstall it also.

**Here is my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pedrycz</groupId>
    <artifactId>tobebought</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tobebought</name>
    <description>Service allowing users to store their shopping lists</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19.0.1</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.passay/passay -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-mapstruct-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Start with removing all `version` tags from the `org.springframework.boot` dependencies and `spring-security-test` (those are managed by the parent) as well as for the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. DItch `jakarta.validation-api`. Remove the `source`/`target` from the `maven-compiler-plugin` andyou want to upgrade the `mapstruct` version to 1.5.3. Also as the scope is `provided` for lombok you don't need the exclude.

Comment: @M.Deinum Unfortunately problem still exists

Comment: You removed the exclude as well? You are trying to outsmart things that are already done by Spring Boot as a parent and the starters. The problem is the exclude as it doesn't allow a version but you shouldn't need the exclude as a provided dependency isn't included anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum removing exclude worked, I thought that it was necessary since I was trying to run mapstruct with lombok. Thank you very much

Comment: The plugin configuration for maven-compiler-plugin to use source/target with Java 8 is simply wrong. Spring Boot 3.X requires minimum JDK17... which is also in contradiction to the given `java.version` property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the exclude, which you don't need, as an exclude only allows for a `groupId` and `artifactId` to be set, no `version`. But as stated you don't need the exclude.

Looking at your `pom.xml` you are also trying to outsmart other parts of the dependency management and configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pedrycz</groupId>
    <artifactId>tobebought</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tobebought</name>
    <description>Service allowing users to store their shopping lists</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19.0.1</java.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- `spring-boot-starter-validation` already contains the needed dependencies, no need for `jakarta.validation-api` as a dependency
- The `spring-boot-starter-parent` will already manage the dependencies for the starters and supported dependencies (like `spring-security-test`) no need to specify a version
- No version for the `maven-compiler-plugin` and no `source`/`target` those are already set and managed by the `spring-boot-starter-parent` you want to extend the configuration
- Upgrade to a newer Mapstruct version and use a version property
- No version for the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` already managed by the `spring-boot-starter-parent` and the `exclude` doesn't support `version` as it will automatically exclude the dependency for that specific version (that is basically how excludes work).

Comment: "the exclude isn't needed as well as the dependency is provided and thus not part of the archive" - that is wrong, unlike other maven plugins, the behaviour of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is [counterintuitive](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/413)

Comment: A **** you are right, I totally forgot about that... Updated the answer to reflect that.